# Node.JS cluster module - Multi-server cluster?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Am I able to make Node.JS multi-machine cluster with [native cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or this module can be used to split work just between CPU threads on same machine?

Comment: This is not possible, sounds like you’re looking for something like [Kubermetes](https://kubernetes.io/) or NGINX like [@shubh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7849549/shubh) said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per docs

> A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take
>   advantage of **multi-core systems**, the user will sometimes want to
>   launch a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.

So obviously it will work on the same machine .

But in your scenario what you can do is distribute requests to different machines using Any Proxy server Like **Nginx**

It distributes the [request](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/round-robin-load-balancing/) ,to the multiple backend machines.
Also see [Nginx Load Balancing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/).

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server backend1.example.com weight=5; // machine 2 ip
        server backend2.example.com; // machine 1 ip
        server 192.0.0.1 backup; // machine 3 ip
    }
}
```

And in those machine you can create clusters or better use any Cluster Manager like [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

Comment: I was more thinking about doing some kind of distributd system without SPOF like proxy with this module, but this answer clearly explains why cluster module is not capable of multi server cluster. Thanks.